# postgreSQL - find next lesson for specific instruments

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a PostgreSQL query to list the two instruments that are available for rent, with the lowest monthly rental fee, also tell when the next lesson for each listed instrument is scheduled. I have these two tables:

```
//Table lesson
lesson_id | instrument_type | start
001       | 01            | 2021-02-01 
002       | 01            | 2021-02-02
003       | 02            | 2021-02-04
004       | 02            | 2021-02-05
005       | 03            | 2021-02-06

//Table instrument
instrument_id | fee_per_month | availability
01            | 300           | yes
02            | 400           | no
03            | 500           | yes
```

And I want:

```
instrument_type | fee_per_month | lesson_id | start
01            | 300           | 001       | 2021-02-01
03            | 500           | 005       | 2021-02-06
```

SQL is new to me, and I have tried my best but didn't succeed:

```
SELECT
instrument.type AS "instrument",
instrument.fee_per_month AS "fee/month",
lesson.start AS "next lesson"

FROM instrument, lesson

LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT lesson.*
    FROM lesson
    WHERE lesson.start >= current_timestamp AND lesson.instrument_type = instrument.type
    ORDER BY lesson.start
    limit 1
) lesson on true
GROUP BY "instrument", "rent/month", "next lesson"
ORDER BY "rent/month"
limit 2;
```

How should I do it correctly?

Comment: Just to clarify, in the first table you got two `004` in `lesson_id` are this typo or intended?

Comment: It was a typo. Now it is fixed @T.Peter

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you are sort of on the right track.  If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT i.instrument_id AS "instrument", i.fee_per_month,
       l.lesson_id, l.start AS "next lesson"
FROM instrument i LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT l.*
      FROM lesson l
      WHERE l.start >= current_timestamp AND
            l.instrument_id = i.instrument_id
      ORDER BY l.start
      LIMIT 1
     ) l
     ON true
WHERE i.availability = 'yes'
ORDER BY i.fee_per_month
LIMIT 2;
```

This fixes up the query, the logic, and the names of things.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c7612d9ff1a76ffcfc067617e6b0aa6d) is a db<>fiddle.

The major differences are:

- No Cartesian product between `instrument` and `lesson`.
- Introducing table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Remove the `GROUP BY`.  No aggregation is necessary.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the left join lateral. It gave me all lessons, regardless date and availability

Comment: @WarMachine68 . . . I fixed the query and added a fiddle.  It seems to work.